# AWS + Drupal email

Tags: amazon-web-services, drupal, drupal-7, smtp, sendmail

Hi I am running on Drupal 7.56, when I moved over my site to AWS cloud the emails stopped being sent/received. I read about AWS SES and I installed SMTP to try and fix emails being sent/received. Apache has sendmail installed and

Here is what I have:

admin/config/system/smtp:

Turn this module on or off:

[x] on

Turn on delivery of emails:

[x] on

SMTP server:

email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com

SMTP port:

465

Use encrypted protocol:

Use SSL

SMTP AUTHENTICATION

Username: [x]

Password: (blank, because every time I enter it, it accepts it and leaves it blank thereafter)

E-mail from address:

x@gmail.com

SEND TEST E-MAIL

E-mail address to send a test e-mail to:

x@gmail.com

I then get this log

---

```
SMTP.module is active.
The configuration options have been saved.
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com (hide key) "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP (hide key) "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP (hide key)
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 10485760 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 Ok "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250 Ok "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250 Ok
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "235 Authentication successful. "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "235 Authentication successful. "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 Ok "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250 Ok "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250 Ok
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 Ok "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250 Ok "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250 Ok
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF> "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF> "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 Ok 0101015fff5750b0-3f553350-bcf3-49e5-affd-b867b1a37e5f-000000 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250 Ok 0101015fff5750b0-3f553350-bcf3-49e5-affd-b867b1a37e5f-000000 "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250 Ok 0101015fff5750b0-3f553350-bcf3-49e5-affd-b867b1a37e5f-000000
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "221 Bye "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "221 Bye "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: @byemsg
A test e-mail has been sent to x@gmail.com You may want to check the logs for any error messages.
SMTP.module is active.
```

but no email in my spam or unread messages and the logs say there was an email sent. Any info or redirects would help a lot. Thank you.

Comment: And when you go to Reports -> Recent log messages do you see some errors there?

Comment: No I do not see any error log, but I do see smtp that shows the email log

Answer (score 0):

By Default, AWS blocks SMTP on port 25 for EC2 instances.

If you are running your Drupal instances on EC2, then there is a good chance that your email servers are working just fine, but the problem is at the networking level.

There is a good article [here](https://www.drupalconnect.com/blog/articles/drupal-not-sending-email-lets-debug-it) about how to debug your drupal email issues.

The AWS documentation about port 25 being blocked can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/)

What you will likely need to do is set up Elastic IPs for your EC2 instances and then set up rDNS. Once that is configured AWS required you to submit an application to request removing the default network block on outgoing SMTP traffic.